# Differentiable function is nonnegative

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $f$ is a differentiable real-valued function on an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is increasing if and only if $f'$ is nonnegative at each point of the interval.

I know how to do the converse, assuming first that $f'(x)\ge 0$ but I don't know how prove assuming first that $f$ is increasing and then arriving that $f'(x)\ge0$.

Comment: @Tom: maybe this was edited after your post, but the condition is $f'(0) \geq 0$.

Comment: @user99680 Yes! It has been edited. Thanks for the update.. I'll delete my previous comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is an increasing function, then $$\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$ is non-negative for sufficiently small $h$, and so taking the limit as $h \to 0$ gives a non-negative result.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Remember that the definition of an increasing function is that $x>y$ , then $f(x)>f(y)$

Comment: @user104235 What part? Do you see why the quotient is non-negative?

Comment: Well, what I got from your hint is that if $f$ is increasing function (which means $x<y \implies f(x)<f(y)$) then $f'(x)$ is nonnegative which is what we were trying to prove? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @user104235 Your question says that you're trying to prove that $f'(x)$ is not negative. And this shows that $f'$ is not negative, since it's the limit of a sequence of non-negative quantities.

Comment: I see it now. Its easier to see using $\lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$. Thanks!

Comment: However please note that this approach can't be used to show first part : $f'(x)\geq 0$ implies $f$ is increasing. This requires the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use Lagrange's MVT to show that for an increasing function,the first derivative has to be positive.

Suppose the function $f(x)$ is continuous in [a,b] and differentiable in (a,b). Then by Lagrange's MVT $\exists$ c $\in$(a,b) such that
$$f\prime (c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
$$\Rightarrow (b-a)f\prime(c)=f(b)-f(a)$$
Since b>a, the sign of the RHS is decided by $f\prime(c)$. If $f\prime(c)$>0,f(b)-f(a)>0 .All other statements follow easily.